# Mupltiple sourcebus found NREL Ditto Python Package

Tags: file-conversion

I am trying to convert CYME to OpenDSS. I have two feeder in the cyme network. The two feeders are not connected. When I use the Ditto tool, the following error is coming. Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

File "C:\Users\amamun1\My Drive\Spring 23\Cyme_OpenDSS_3\ditto\modify\system_structure.py", line 68, in init
raise ValueError("Mupltiple sourcebus found: {srcs}".format(srcs=srcs))

ValueError: Mupltiple sourcebus found: ['SOURCE_S5100_src' 'SOURCE_S6201_src']

I want to convert the CYME database model to be converted into OpenDSS format.